# Programming query execution Postgres

Tags: postgresql, windows, cron

I need to execute update querys routinely over a Postgres table. Is it possible to program an automatic execution of the query, let's say, every day at 15:00 hs? The Postgres version is 9.5, I'm working on Windows 7.

Comment: Windows has a [scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) - have you tried using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no task scheduling functionality built into PostgreSQL.

You can use an extension like [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron), but I don't know how easy it is to build that on Windows.

The simplest way would probably to use the [Windows task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) to start your job regularly.